# What is the prescriptive approach to supporting multiple RDBMS's with Flyway?

Tags: flyway

I have an application that supports multiple RDBMS's.  The SQL needed to build the data model is different between each of the RDBMS's that I need to support.  The differences aren't small either, they stem from the fact that one of the supported systems is expected for light use (development, small installations) and heavy use.  Simply standardizing on a single supported RDBMS is not an option.

As it stands I need to be able to apply migrations to my application in all of the supported RDBMS's.  Where possible I'd like to be able to share migration scripts to reduce the amount of duplication involved but I imagine that isn't entirely possible.

The only approach I can come up with so far is to keep separate directories in source control for each of the supported environments.  Then at runtime, pick the appropriate directory for the RDBMS that the system is connected to.

Is having one directory per supported RDBMS the prescriptive approach or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right from the FAQ: [What is the best strategy for handling database-specific sql?](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq.html#db-specific-sql)